# Coverlet lcov.info file not generated for dotnet core project

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-code, code-coverage, lcov, coverlet

I'm working on dotnet core project withd VS code inside a linux machine.

following below blog to generate coverage report:
https://www.hanselman.com/blog/AutomaticUnitTestingInNETCorePlusCodeCoverageInVisualStudioCode.aspx

as mentioned there Im passing dotnet test arguments as below:

```
dotnet test /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=lcov /p:CoverletOutput=./lcov.info
```

and expecting to lcov.info file to be generated, but it doesn't.

am I missing anything here?

ps: I have this package already included

```
 <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="1.3.0">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I use to have the exact problem. Hanselman's guide never explicitly instructs the reader that the package `coverlet.msbuild` is required to instruct .NET to collect code coverage using the `/p:` syntax. Include `coverlet.msbuild` in a test project by executing the following command inside the test project folder:

```
dotnet add package coverlet.msbuild
```

The test project's `*.csproj` file should include a statement similar to the following:

```
<PackageReference Include="coverlet.msbuild" Version="2.9.0"
    <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
</PackageReference>
```

With this fix, VSCode's Coverage Gutters extension works out of the box for me when I run the exact same command as you posted.