# Coverage-Gutter extension for visual studio code is not showing line coverage - .NET

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-code, code-coverage

For .net unit testing I installed Coverage Gutter in visual studio code.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryanluker.vscode-coverage-gutters.

But is not showing the line coverage.

when I press Coverage Gutter display coverage or press the "watch" option in the footer it says "Could not find coverage file"

Error:

`Could not find a Coverage file! Searched for lcov.info, cov.xml, coverage.xml, jacoco.xml, coverage.cobertura.xml`

[image: Project structure]

my setting.json

```
{

  "dotnet-test-explorer.testProjectPath": "**/*test.csproj",
  "dotnet-test-explorer.runInParallel": true,
  "coverage-gutters.showLineCoverage": true,
  "dotnet-test-explorer.testArguments": "/p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=lcov /p:CoverletOutput=../../lcov.info",
  "coverage-gutters.coverageBaseDir": "**",
  "coverage-gutters.coverageFileNames": [
    "lcov.info",
    "cov.xml",
    "coverage.xml",
    "jacoco.xml",
    "coverage.cobertura.xml"
  ]
}
```

I think the issue is in  `"coverage-gutters.coverageBaseDir": "**",`
Can anyone help me to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I followed [this Scott Hanselman's blog](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/automatic-unit-testing-in-net-core-plus-code-coverage-in-visual-studio-code) and [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64172357/1955268) to make it work for me. Here is the summary of what is needed:

If your `lcov.info` file is not generated, try adding the `coverlet.msbuild` package to your test project and then run the tests again.

```
dotnet add package coverlet.msbuild
```

Your test arguments are correct, just ensure that it generates the `lcov.info` file inside the workspace folder. Coverage gutters extension can by default read `lcov.info` file within any workspace folder to show the coverage so you don't need to specify the `coverageFileNames` and `coverageBaseDir` settings.

Answer (score 0):

Settings.json

Below configuration for solution with multiple test projects, it automatically creates TestCover folder with Icov.info file for all test projects.

```
{

"dotnet-test-explorer.autoExpandTree": true,

"dotnet-test-explorer.autoWatch": true,

"dotnet-test-explorer.treeMode": "full",

"dotnet-test-explorer.testArguments": "/p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=lcov /p:CoverletOutput=./TestCover/lcov.info",

"dotnet-test-explorer.testProjectPath": "**/*.csproj",

"coverage-gutters.coverageFileNames":[
    "lcov.info",
    "cov.xml",
    "coverage.xml",
    "jacoco.xml",
    "coverage.cobertura.xml",
    "coverage.json"        
  ] 
}
```

For individual test project change below config line to:-

```
"dotnet-test-explorer.testProjectPath": "yourtestproject.csproj",
```

Run commands for solution with multiple test projects:-

```
dotnet test yoursolution.sln /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=lcov /p:CoverletOutput=./lcov.info
```

Run commands for solution with single test project:-

```
dotnet test yourtestproject.csproj /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=lcov /p:CoverletOutput=./lcov.info
```